# Delphi DBExpress error with turkish collation

Tags: sql-server, delphi, collation, dbexpress

I lately found a problem with a delphi program created with Delphi 2007 and dbExpress components. This program is used in many countries with a collation set to the local language so people have a familiar sorting etc. We never had a problem with a database collation.

But now that we want to bring the program to turkey we face a problem which is an error message saying: "Invalid object name 'SYSINDEXES'" when using a Turkish collation.

I was using the collation 'Turkish_CI_AS'.

I also found another person who had a problem with a turkish collation here: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/56/568380.html (4. post on the page)

He states that delphi uses upper case strings here instead of lowercase that would be correct. This makes sense since in turkish 'i' and 'I' are different characters even if you use a case insensitive collation.

The question is now if there is any way to fix this without messing arround too much. I mean I don't want to get bigger problems by fixing this intermediate one.

Comment: My guess is that the easiest solution would be to have the database collation something compatible with dbexpress, while character columns having a Turkish collation. Meanwhile you can launch a QC report..